# How to change format String from Json response?

Tags: android, json, string-formatting

I want to ask. I got a string json response like this

```
"Bank Danamon|Reksa Dana Insight Money Syariah"
```

And i want to change that string to like this in Android setText

```
Bank Danamon 
Reksa Dana Insight Money Syariah
```

This is the code when i set the response

```
 txvSettlementName.setText(itemSettlement.getAccountName());
```

Is there a way to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: Use `.split` function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the string like

```
String str = "Bank Danamon|Reksa Dana Insight Money Syariah";
String[] separated = str.split("|");

separated[0]; // this will contain "Bank Danamon"
separated[1]; // this will contain " Reksa Dana Insight Money Syariah"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String accountName = itemSettlement.getAccountName();
accountName = accountName.replace("|","\n");
txvSettlementName.setText(accountName);
```

This code will directly replace the character `|` with line break `\n` which you can directly set to `TextView`

Comment: i use StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "|"); and it's done

Comment: At the end, what was your requirement? Show the string in two different textViews or single textView?